# ¿Cómo puedo guardar la información de un Activity temporalmente?

Tags: android, android-studio

tengo un activity con 3 fragmentos en los cuales puedo subir información para  después enviar a una base de datos, guardo texto(una descripción), imágenes, vídeos, pdf, docx y audios. Lo que debo hacer es que si la persona no envía la información, se guarde temporalmente hasta que la persona envié dicha información, y esto debe hacerse aunque la persona cierre la app. ¿alguna idea de que puedo hacer?

He aquí un ejemplo:

Primero sube la información 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces la persona puede salir de la actividad, o cerrar la app y se debería guardar, pero regreso y esta vacía 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Guardalo en la base de sqlite3 con un status de envio.

Comment: No has intentado trabajar con los SharedPreferences

Comment: Leí sobre los SharedPreferences, pero no se abre siempre la misma tarea, hay muchas tareas diferentes que abren la misma activity, si lo hago con SharedPreferences te abriría la misma información para todas las tareas

Comment: Por eso tendrias que crear una clave de sharedPreferences por cada tarea,al final supongo tu sabes identificar las tareas, es decir: si tienes Tarea 1:
tus charedPreferences serian algo a si:  tarea1chares -> valor1, tarea1chares -> valor2, tarea1chares -> valor3, tarea2chares -> valor1, tarea2chares -> valor2 etc.
De lo contrario usa una BD como sql lite como te comenta Juan .

Comment: guarda el "estado" con SharedPref dentro de onPause, para en caso de cerrar la app. Una vez guardado los datos a Sqlite vacía ese SharedPreference. La otra opción es onSaveInstanceState para en caso de por ejemplo girar la pantalla y no se pierdan los datos

Comment: Supongo que lo intentaré con SharedPreferences con id's por ahora, si se vuelvo más complejo tendré que hacer sqlite, gracias a todos

Comment: si es a una base de datos externa no necesitar sqlite, solo SharedPreferences y onSaveInstanceState

Comment: si queires algo rapido con SharedPref te pude valer, pero lo que tu estan intentado seria mejor usando una sqlite, crea las entidades y las vas guardando si no tienes conexion y cuando la tenga envia los datos que estan guardados, creo que es mucho mejor un sqlite

Comment: por que le pones cerrado a tu pregunta?

Comment: xd Porque implemente los SharedPreferences y me funciono, y no se como cerrar la pregunta :v bien, para que ya aparezca como contestada

Comment: la pregunta no será cerrada, debes usar el espacio de abajo que es la zona de respuestas para publicar tu solución, luego aceptar tu respuesta para que aparezca la palomita verde y con eso basta, pues no es correcto colocar eso en el título

Comment: xd Okey, no lo sabia, muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final use SharedPreferences ya que el usar sqlite sería problemático por posibles relaciones que tendría que realizar y como la información que uso solo es temporal hasta que el usuario encuentre una zona con internet para poder enviar la información o termine de rellenar la Evidencia. hice esto:

Antes de que se salga del activity guardo la información.

Primero creo un espacio diferente para guardar información por tarea:

`SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(""+idevent, MODE_PRIVATE);`
`SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(""+idevent, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();`

Entonces empiezo a guardar la información de forma temporal según texto, imágenes, vídeo y todo tipo de archivos que tenga subidos al activity

```
                        editor.putInt("contImg", contImg);
                        editor.putInt("contUris", contUris);
                        editor.putString("edObserv",edObserv);
                        if (contImg!=0) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < contImg; i++) {
                                String src = multimedia.get(i).getSrc();
                                String lat = String.valueOf(multimedia.get(i).getUbication().getLat());
                                String lng = String.valueOf(multimedia.get(i).getUbication().getLng());
                                String created_at = multimedia.get(i).getCreated_at();
                                String type = multimedia.get(i).getType();

                                editor.putString("type"+i, type);
                                editor.putString("src"+i, src);
                                editor.putString("lng"+i, lat);
                                editor.putString("lat"+i, lng);
                                editor.putString("created_at"+i, created_at);


                            }

                        }else{
                            if (prefs.getInt("contImg",0)!=0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < prefs.getInt("contImg", 0); i++) {
                                    editor.remove("type" + i);
                                    editor.remove("src" + i);
                                    editor.remove("lng" + i);
                                    editor.remove("lat" + i);
                                    editor.remove("created_at" + i);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (contUris!=0){
                            for (int i=0; i<contUris; i++){
                                String src = files.get(i).getSrc();
                                String name = files.get(i).getName();
                                String created_at = files.get(i).getCreated_at();
                                String type = files.get(i).getType();

                                editor.putString("f_type"+i, type);
                                editor.putString("f_src"+i, src);
                                editor.putString("f_name"+i, name);
                                editor.putString("f_created_at"+i, created_at);

                            }
                        }else{
                            if (prefs.getInt("contUris",0)!=0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < prefs.getInt("contImg", 0); i++) {
                                    editor.remove("f_type" + i);
                                    editor.remove("f_src" + i);
                                    editor.remove("f_name"+i);
                                    editor.remove("f_created_at" + i);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        editor.commit();
```

`

Una vez salio de la tarea/evento, y vuelve a entrar a el, la información aparece de nuevo llamándola al inicio y se guarda con este código.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(""+idevent, MODE_PRIVATE);
contImg = prefs.getInt("contImg", 0);
contUris = prefs.getInt("contUris", 0);

    edObserv = prefs.getString("edObserv", "");
    if (contImg!= 0){
        for (int i=0; i<contImg; i++) {
            Foto photo = new Foto();
            photo.setType(prefs.getString("type" + i, "0"));
            photo.setSrc(prefs.getString("src" + i, "0"));
            photo.getUbication().setLng(Double.valueOf(prefs.getString("lng" + i, "0")));
            photo.getUbication().setLat(Double.valueOf(prefs.getString("lat" + i, "0")));
            photo.setCreated_at(prefs.getString("created_at" + i, "0"));


            if (photo.getType().equals("image")){
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo.getSrc());
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(photo.getSrc()));

                ListVideos.add( uri);
                mTypeAdapter.add( "Photo");
                mItemChecked.add( false);
                mImageBitmap.add( bitmap);
                multimedia.add( photo);
            }

            if (photo.getType().equals("gallery")){
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo.getSrc());
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(photo.getSrc()));

                ListVideos.add( uri);
                mTypeAdapter.add( "Photo");
                mItemChecked.add( false);
                mImageBitmap.add( bitmap);
                multimedia.add( photo);
            }

            if (photo.getType().equals("video")){
                Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(EvidenceActivity.this.getResources(),
                        R.drawable.reproductor_multimedia);

                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(photo.getSrc()));
                ListVideos.add(uri);
                mTypeAdapter.add( "Video");
                mItemChecked.add( false);
                mImageBitmap.add( icon);
                multimedia.add( photo);
            }
        }
    }

    if (contUris!=0){
        for (int i=0; i<contUris; i++){
            Files file = new Files();
            file.setType(prefs.getString("f_type" + i, "0"));
            file.setSrc(prefs.getString("f_src" + i, "0"));
            file.setName(prefs.getString("f_name" + i, "0"));
            file.setCreated_at(prefs.getString("f_created_at" + i, "0"));

            ArchivosUris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(file.getSrc())));
            Type_Archivo.add(file.getType());
            Name_Archivo.add(file.getName());
            archivoChecked.add(false);
            files.add(file);

        }
    }
```

Entonces al final que envía la información y ya no es necesaria la información que había guardado con anterioridad la borro con esto

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(""+idevent, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.clear().commit();
```

Y listo! espero que a alguien más les sirva, y si tienen dudas de algo que hice me pueden decir, también gracias a todos aquellos que me ayudaron con sus comentarios.